# iOS: Using typhoon in app extension, specifically messages extension

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, ios-app-extension, typhoon, ios-messages-extension

I am using typhoon to perform dependency injection in my app. It works well in the regular app. However, in the messages extension of the app storyboard don't work as expected - injections are not working in the view controllers.
I have added the 'TyphoonInitialAssemblies' key in the extension target info plist, just like in the regular app target. 
Do I need to do anything special to make typhoon work in extensions?

Comment: I'm with the same issue here, and believe it's because of the lifecycle of the app extension. have you found any solution so far?